# Can you filter the allowable CultureInfo types for a ASP.NET website?

Tags: asp.net, globalization

I could definitely accomplish what I want with a custom handler, but I was hoping it would be possible to adjust the web.config to define allowable cultures. Basically, I have a website that has resource files for a number of languages. I would like to deploy the same website to different domains with different configurations specifying the default cultures. I know I can set a specific culture to be used in the web.config, but can I also specify multiple cultures?

Even though I have English language resource files, I don't want a visitor from the US to certain domains to see the English version, but I can't fix the site for a single culture, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are asking three different questions:

> Can you filter for the cultures used?

Yes. Create a base class for all your pages where you override the Page.InitializeCulture method and only allow certian cultures to be used.

> Can you do it in web.config?

No. The best you can do in the web.config file is indicate a single culture.

> Can you limit users from certain geographical places on the net?

This is a tougher question. First, you will never have perfect filtering as the Internet makes this pretty much impossible. However, you can get close by geo-locating based on IP. See [Geolocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation_software) for more. There are a number of services on the net that will provide this functionality for you.

Comment: I was really just asking if it can be done through the web.config, and it looks like the answer is no